# How do I get Spring Data REST 2.0 RC1 to work?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I got Spring Data REST 1.1.0.M1 working, but would like to try version 2.0.

Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ca.mynamespace</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>rested_development</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>rested_development</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.3</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try SDR 2.0.0.R1, I get `ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration` and when I try HATEOAS 0.9, I get `IllegalArgumentException: Content must not be a collection! Use Resources instead!`

Comment: This is a very vague question. Would you mind adding a bit more information? Show the repository you added, show the general declaration of the entity. Show, what exactly is not working. What do you expect to see, what is it that you think is missing/broken?

Comment: @OliverGierke updated my question with POM. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the correct set of dependency versions. If you want to upgrade to Spring Data REST 2.0, you also need to upgrade to the according versions of other Spring Data modules contained in the release train. So you'll need:

- Spring Data REST 2.0.0.RC1
- Spring Data JPA 1.5.0.RC1 (as indicated in the POM of Spring Data REST)
- Spring HATEOAS 0.9.0.RELEASE (also indicated in the POM of Spring Data REST)

Comment: ...and it works. I'll buy you some good Canadian beer if you're ever in Vancouver

Comment: Glad it works for you! And I'll get back to that… :)